# What are the standard dimensions for the square grips on PVC screw caps?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, pvc

[image]
[image]

No matter the size of the end cap, the square grip always seems to be exactly the same size.

What is the standard size of the square grip?
(NPT?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a few random supply websites for "clean out plug wrenches" there doesn't appear to be a fixed size.  the wrenches are sold in 5-6 different sizes, and there are external and internal sizes since the plugs can be installed upside down.

Here is a site that sells the wrenches: [Heavy Duty Supplies](http://heavydutysupplies.com/square-socket-for-raised-head-clean-out-plugs-1/)